# Shiny: if statement after updateSelectInput

Tags: r, shiny

I need to update my slider according to some features; and I am doing it by using the command updateSelectinput. Then I need to put some if statements based on these choices: how can I recall them? the usual "if(input$x== input$x[1])" does not seems to work; or better, it works only for the first one ([1]) but not the others.

Here (part) of my code:

```
ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("TITOLO",
tabPanel("Per tipologia",
sidebarPanel(selectInput(inputId = "x", label = "x",
        choices = "" ) ),
...
server <- function(input, output, session) {
observe({
database_list <- database_analysis()
database_list <- aggregate(database_list$y ~ database_list$t, 
FUN=sum)
names(database_list)[names(database_list) == "database_list$t"] <- "t"
a <- paste(database_list$t,"-",database_list$t-9)
b <- paste(database_list$t,"-",database_list$t-3)
c <- database_list$t

updateSelectInput(session, "x",
                label = "x",
                choices = c(a,b,c,database_list$t-1,database_list$t-2,database_list$t-3,database_list$t-4,database_list$t-5,database_list$t-6,database_list$t-7,database_list$t-8,database_list$t-9, database_list$t-10))
 })
 RE1 <- reactive({

database_a <- database_analysis()
...
  req(input$x)
          if(input$x== input$x[1]) {
          return(database_outp_x[1,])}
          else
           if(input$x== input$x[2]) {
          return(database_outp_x[2,])}
          else
          {
          return(database_outp_disa)}


  })
```

Comment: what do you exactly want to access with the statement `input$x[1]`?

Comment: If in the slider the first element is selected do the first part; else if is the second, do the second part and so on and so forth